# Route data instead of querystring?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm new to MVC. I have an Index view that shows a list of a table. And all rows of the table have Detail, Update and Delete linkbuttons. I create links like below;

```
@Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Display", new { _ID = item.ID })
@Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update", new { _ID = item.ID })
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { _ID = item.ID })
```

My route registration like below. They are in Area.

```
        context.MapRoute(
            name: "Assignments_Action",
            url: "Assignments/{action}/{_ID}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Assignments", _ID = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            name: "Assignments_List",
            url: "Assignments/{action}/{_Page}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Assignments", _Page = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        context.MapRoute(
            "Assignments_default",
            "Assignments/{controller}/{action}/{_ID}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", _ID = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And my controllers like below;

```
public ViewResult Display(int _ID)
{
    //blabla
    return View(assignmentsModel);
}

[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Update(int _ID)
{
    //blabla
    return View("Index");
}

[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public RedirectToRouteResult Update(AssignmentsModel _assignmentsModel)
{
    //blabla
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public ActionResult Delete(int _ID)
{
    //blabla
    return View();
}
```

But the links are created with querystring: `localhost:1111/Assignments/Display?_ID=399`

Not like routedata: `localhost:1111/Assignments/Display/399`.

If I type in a URL like `localhost:1111/Assignments/Display/399` myself, it works fine.

But it doesn't get created by itself.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need three routes, only one. Keep any of the three, delete the rest, and delete the `action = "..."` from the one you keep.

Comment: `They are in Area.` - are you sure you need an area? Did you create it properly?

Comment: Ok. I changed my route registration code. If i write Assignment_List before Assignment_Action it creates with querystring. If i write Assignment_Action before Assignment_List it works like i want with route data. But at this time _Page parameter of AssignmentList doesn't work :S

Comment: No no. it works fine now :) I really don't know why bu it worked :) i wrote Assignment_Action before Assignment_List and the _Page parameter was nullable and in controller i wrote if it's null _Page = 1, it worked fine.

Comment: It works fine because route matching stops as soon as it finds the first root that matches the conditions, in the order they were registered. Even if there is a better matching route later, it will not be found. That is why you put more specific routes at the top and less specific rules at the bottom.